# Can't properly fetch GridFS image on Angular app

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, mongoose

I'm really a newbie with Angular, MongoDB, so I'm asking for your help ! 
I'm trying to display images on an Angular App
Images are saved using Gridfs and sent to the app with fs.createReadStream

```
//The model
const ProfilePic = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        _id : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        lenght: Number,
        chunksize: Number,
        uploadDate: Date,
        filename: String,
        md5: String,
        contentType: String
    }
);

// Create storage engine
const storage = new GridFsStorage({
  url: mongoURI,

  file: (req, file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const filename = file.originalname;
      const fileInfo = {
        filename: filename,
        bucketName: "ProfilePic"
      };
      resolve(fileInfo);
    });
  }
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

router.post("/setProfilePic", upload.single("picture"), (req, res) => {
  console.log("image received");
  return res.status(200).json({err: "no"})
});


router.get('/getProfilePic/:filename', (req, res) => {
  gfs.collection('ProfilePic'); //set collection name to lookup into

  /** First check if file exists */
  gfs.files.find({filename: req.params.filename}).toArray(function(err, files){
      if(!files || files.length === 0){
          return res.status(404).json({
              responseCode: 1,
              responseMessage: "error"
          });
      }
      // create read stream
      var readstream = gfs.createReadStream({
          filename: files[0].filename,
          root: "ProfilePic"
      });
      // set the proper content type 
      res.set('Content-Type', files[0].contentType)
      // Return response
      return readstream.pipe(res);
  });
});

// method used to fetch the image
async getProfilePic(name) {
    return this.http.get(this.url + "user/getProfilePic/" + name);
  }
```

Here's the error I get on the application : 
Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0

What is wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client/browser is trying to parse the response as json since that's the default. Just pass an object with a responseType attribute set to 'blob' and it should work.

```
// method used to fetch the image
async getProfilePic(name) {
    return this.http.get(this.url + "user/getProfilePic/" + name, {responseType: 'blob'});
}
```

https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest#responseType